# FileNotFoundError al intentar cargas el dataset "iris"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy empezando en pandas y en IA, apenas aprendí Python hace poco, pasa que estaba viendo un tutorial de principiantes sobre Pandas 
me salta este error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File data.iris.data does not exist: 'data.iris.data'

y este es mi código:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.iris.data', header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

El error simplemente indica que el archivo no se ha podido encontrar, nada más.

Pandas lo usa para sus test, pero hasta dónde yo se no se a incluido nunca  en la instalación. Si que se incluye por defecto en `scikit-learn`, junto a otros:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris_dataset = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris_dataset.data, columns = iris_dataset.feature_names)
# Añadimos la columna con la especie
df['species'] = pd.Series(
    iris_dataset["target_names"][iris_dataset["target"]]
    )
```

También `seaborn` lo incluye, y es más simple aún ya que genera el DataFrame directamente:

```
import seaborn as sb


df = sb.load_dataset('iris')
```

Otra opción es que lo descargues directamente desde el repositorio oficial de 
[UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu):

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_url)
```

Puedes descargarlo y alojarlo en tu directorio de trabajo de tu script con el nombre `iris.csv` y luego simplemente cargarlo con `df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")`

Dado que es un dataset tan popular y conocido para el testeo de técnicas clasificaciones en ia, es común que bibliotecas relacionadas con éste campo lo incluyan por defecto.